# C# Parallel.Foreach int[] in List<T> not changed properly

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

This is my class:

```
public class UnusedRolesOccurrence
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public int[] Month { get { return month; } set { month = value; } }
    private static int[] month = new int[12];
}
```

And this is where I want to fill the int array with values:

```
Parallel.ForEach(unusedrolesoccurrence, (UnusedRolesOccurrence item) =>
{
    try
    {
        lock (listLock)
        {

            int count = tmp.Count(x => x.Username == item.Username && x.Role == item.Role);
            item.Month[month] = count;

            if (count > 2)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Username},{item.Role},{month}={count},{item.Month[month]}");
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //
    }
});
```

`List<unusedrolesoccurrence>` is pre-populated with data. Month array is [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] before starting foreach, with `int[] arr_month = new int[12];`.

`tmp` is also a `List<t>`.

What is not working: during loop, count and also the value of `item.Month[month]` is correct. But not in the target `List<UnusedRolesOccurrence>`. All Month are the same value of the last count processed in the loop, e.g. [3,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] or [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]. And because parallel, it is always different the result of course.

I changed `int[]` to `public Dictionary<int, int> Month { get; set; }` for testing, but same behavior.

HERE EXAMPLE CODE( with // the secondary try with dictionary with same result):

```
public class UnusedRoles
        {
            public string Username { get; set; }
            public string Role { get; set; }
            public int Month { get; set; }
        }

        public class UnusedRolesOccurrence
        {
            public string Username { get; set; }
            public string Role { get; set; }
            //public Dictionary<int, int> Month { get; set; }
            public int[] Month { get { return month; } set { month = value; } }
            public int[] month = new int[12];
        }

        public List<UnusedRoles> unusedroles = new List<UnusedRoles>();
        public List<UnusedRolesOccurrence> unusedrolesoccurrence = new List<UnusedRolesOccurrence>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Run();
        }

        public async void Run()
        {
            unusedroles.Clear();
            unusedrolesoccurrence.Clear();

            Dictionary<int, int> dictionary_month = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            //for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) { dictionary_month.Add(i, 0); }
            int[] arr_month = new int[12];

            unusedroles.Add(new UnusedRoles { Username = "User1", Role = "A", Month = 0 });
            unusedroles.Add(new UnusedRoles { Username = "User1", Role = "A", Month = 0 });
            unusedroles.Add(new UnusedRoles { Username = "User1", Role = "B", Month = 0 });
            unusedroles.Add(new UnusedRoles { Username = "User2", Role = "A", Month = 0 });
            unusedroles.Add(new UnusedRoles { Username = "User2", Role = "B", Month = 0 });
            unusedroles.Add(new UnusedRoles { Username = "User2", Role = "B", Month = 0 });
            unusedroles.Add(new UnusedRoles { Username = "User3", Role = "C", Month = 0 });
            unusedroles.Add(new UnusedRoles { Username = "User3", Role = "C", Month = 0 });
            unusedroles.Add(new UnusedRoles { Username = "User3", Role = "C", Month = 0 });
            unusedroles.Add(new UnusedRoles { Username = "User4", Role = "A", Month = 0 });

            var tmp = unusedroles.Select(x => new { x.Username, x.Role }).Distinct();

            foreach (var item in tmp)
            {
                unusedrolesoccurrence.Add(new UnusedRolesOccurrence
                {
                    //Username = item.Username, Role = item.Role, Month = dictionary_month
                    Username = item.Username, Role = item.Role, Month = arr_month
                });
            }

            var result = await Find(0);

            foreach (var item in unusedrolesoccurrence)
            {
                //string line = "";
                //foreach (var pair in item.Month) {
                //    line = $"{line},{pair.Value}";
                //}
                string line = $"{item.Username},{item.Role}";
                foreach (int i in item.Month)
                {
                    line = $"{line},{i}";
                }
                //Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Username},{item.Role}{line}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"{line}");

            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> Find(int month)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(unusedrolesoccurrence, (UnusedRolesOccurrence item) =>
                {
                        int count = unusedroles.Count(x => x.Username == item.Username && x.Role == item.Role &&x.Month == month);
                        item.Month[month] = count;
                        Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Username},{item.Role},count={count},item.Month[{month}]={item.Month[month]}");
                });
            });

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Putting a `lock` like this in `Parallel.ForEach`the way you have pretty much renders it useless

Comment: Why are you using a static backing field for an instance property? Don't do that

Comment: I had issues updating the `List`, and an answer from stackoverflow was to add a `lock`.

Comment: @ReneM - Then show us a [mcve] so that we can see it is needed. Please let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: Your month array is static, don't do this.**

The following member of your class `UnusedRolesOccurrence` is shared by *all* instances of that class during the concurrent operation you've set up.

`private static int[] month = new int[12];`

Remove the static keyword and each instance of `UnusedRolesOccurrence` will have its own `.month` array.

**Note:** you might have other problems in this code, but your question comes from this problem here.

Comment: Did not solve the problem. Same behavior. The second try with `public Dictionary<int, int> Month { get; set; }`, it was public and did not work too.

Comment: Then you do indeed have other problems as I suggested.  The next culprit is most likely that `lock` which you shouldn't need once the members of your class are no longer static.  Is it safe to assume "did not work" means that you're having the exact same result?

Comment: I removed the `look` already before, changed from privat to public. Same behavior.

Comment: Even without month being static, you're still assigning all of your objects the exact same month instance. Arrays are allocated on the heap in C# (and passed by reference for assignments); you are only allocating a single one per run.

Answer (score 0):

It is working this way.

Before:

```
        int[] arr_month = new int[12];

        var tmp = unusedroles.Select(x => new { x.Username, x.Role }).Distinct();

        foreach (var item in tmp)
        {
            unusedrolesoccurrence.Add(new UnusedRolesOccurrence
            {
                //Username = item.Username, Role = item.Role, Month = dictionary_month
                Username = item.Username, Role = item.Role, Month = arr_month
            });
        }
```

After:

```
    var tmp = unusedroles.Select(x => new { x.Username, x.Role }).Distinct();

    foreach (var item in tmp)
    {
        unusedrolesoccurrence.Add(new UnusedRolesOccurrence
        {
            //Username = item.Username, Role = item.Role, Month = dictionary_month
            Username = item.Username, Role = item.Role, Month = new int[12]
        });
    }
```